# Efficient inner join on three tables using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I need to join three tables on two conditions and also a where using sql.
 Something like

```
select
    t1.id,t1.name,t2.date,t3.hhh 
from t1 
inner join t2 
    on t1.id = t2.id
inner join t3 
    on t1.name = t3.name
where t1.id = 'gggg'
```

Is there an efficient method to do this?

It takes .492 sec for two rows of result.
I need to minimize the time.

Comment: You wrote that it's oracle, but tagged as sql server? With that amount of information, check that there are indexes for the name fields and id.

Comment: @JamesZ sorry its sql but how do i index name and id field...u mean marking them as primary and secondary keys?

Comment: Look up `create index`

Comment: Show the execution plan for the query, and the approximate volume of data for each of the three tables. Also, verify whether you're actually providing a literal value for `t1.id` (e.g. `'gggg'`) or if you're really using a bind variable (as you probably should).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not up to providing an explain plan (your best bet for a good response), check to see if the columns are indexed.  If they aren't, the following should help.

```
CREATE INDEX t1_idx1 ON t1 (id,name);
CREATE INDEX t1_idx2 ON t1 (name,id);
CREATE INDEX t2_idx1 ON t2 (id,date);
CREATE INDEX t3_idx1 ON t3 (name,hhh);
```

Indexing the columns in the WHERE clause and those that are joined should help a great deal.  However, including those in the SELECT clause should help further by eliminating the need to access the tables altogether.  A word of caution though, adding indexes will slow down your inserts, updates & deletes and take up space.

If you're still having performance issues after addressing the indexing, gather statistics on the tables and indexes.  As Jeffrey Kep suggested, you should also use a bind variable.  Furthermore, the query might benefit from a hint, but that's rarely the case if statistics are up to date.

Really the best answer here though is to learn how to SQL tune by analyzing explain plans.  SQL Developer is free and can easily display explain plans.  At the most basic level, try to eliminate table access (full)'s where possible.  Being able to write the query in your post, you can tune at this level.

Comment: how to to select at1,at2 from table1 where at1='uuu' and then inner join the result with other table?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try left join version of SQL:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.name,
    t2.date,
    t3.hhh
FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t2  ON t1.id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN t3  ON t1.name = t3.name
WHERE t1.id = 'gggg';
```

You also need to create index on PRIMARY KEYS (Unique) and name, date etc... for fast searching.

e.g.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX t1_unique_index_id ON t1(id);
CREATE INDEX idx_t1_name ON t1(NAME);

CREATE INDEX t2_unique_index_date ON t2(date);
CREATE INDEX t3_unique_index_hh ON t3(hhh);
```

Comment: Thank u:) ya it took .295sec now.

Comment: It makes no sense to suggest changing from an inner to an outer join for no logical reason (regardless of any purported performance benefit).

Comment: Also, it's highly unlikely that indexes on `t2.date` or `t3.hhh` will make any difference to this query.

Comment: Inner join used as Cross join means If you have T1 = 10 rows x t2 10 Rows. It will be take time for checking 10x10=100 rows check.

For that I suggested to use `LEFT JOIN` for better performance

date and hhh is not compulsory for indexing.